# How to remove font styles in SharePoint 2013 Ribbon?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ribbon

I am trying to remove styles in the ribbon. The problem is that I can't just use css to do it, because SharePoint has it 5 styles per row in the table tag. My 10 custom styles starts after the build in ones. If I hide them, then it will look weird because in the first row only a few of mine will appear. I would need to use jquery to reorganize it. Is there a cleaner way to do this? Also doing it with javascript I don't think is possible because then I would have to change the default 5 that appears in the ribbon (when dropdown is not opened).

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to remove the default SharePoint RTE styles and show only your own or do you want your own to coexist with SharePoints?

Comment: i want to remove them for everyone.